# Export custom post types as xml?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

For a web page I'm working on I've created a plugin where user can put various members and their info in, and I've created a page template where I output these members out on a page.

This works out as it should, but I'd like to have a 'download as xml' button below this on the page.

So I've tried adding to my page template this

```
<div class="download_button">

    <?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'members',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    $out_array = array();

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

    $mail_array = explode(', ', $post_meta['Members_contact_mail'][0]);
    $email = array();
    if (is_array($mail_array)) {
        foreach ($mail_array as $key) {
            $email[] = $key;
        }
    }

    $phone_array = explode(', ', $post_meta['Members_contact_phone'][0]);
    $phone = array();
    if (is_array($phone_array)) {
        foreach ($phone_array as $key_phone) {
            $phone[] = $key_phone;
        }
    }

    $title = get_the_title();

    $out_array[] = array(
        $title,
        $post_meta['Members_address'][0],
        $post_meta['Members_person_in_charge'][0],
        $post_meta['Members_entry_date'][0],
        $phone,
        $email,
        $post_meta['Members_oib'][0]
        );

    endwhile;

    $phpexcel = new Excel_Xml;
    $phpexcel->addWorksheet('members', $out_array);
// $phpexcel->sendWorkbook('members.xls');

    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $phpexcel->getWorkbook() );?>" download=""><i class="bm-download"></i> <?php esc_html_e('members.xml', 'theme') ?></a>
</div>
```

In my page template I've included the file called `excel_xml.php` that I've got from [here](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel/).

Now the thing that's bothering me is how to create a working download link.

If I uncomment the

```
$phpexcel->sendWorkbook('members.xls');
```

In my `download_button` div I'll actually get the xml file, so I can see that this works. But that's not what I need. I've tried with other functions from `excel_xml.php` file, but none of those worked.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

SOLUTION:

This seems to work:

```
            $phpexcel = new Excel_Xml;
            $phpexcel->addWorksheet('members', $out_array);
            $phpexcel->writeWorkbook('members.xls');

            ?>
            <a class="member_download" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>members.xls" target="_blank"><i class="bm-download"></i> <?php esc_html_e('members.xls', 'theme') ?></a>
```

The `.xls` file is saved to a root folder when you enter a page. When you click on the button it downloads the file.

Comment: if you know the file path where it is created then simply link to generated file, file will be download automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I just kinda figured it out, it saves the workbook in the root folder. Is there a way to make it so that the file is generated when I click on this button instead on page reload?

Comment: i dont know why your page gets reload, but if you link directly with the file with target blank , then a new window will route to the linked and download it automatically . you link must be like `$fileUrl = site_url('/').$filename;
echo '<a href="'.$fileUrl.'" target="_blank">Download As XML</a>';`

Comment: What I meant was, I located the file with FTP, and I deleted it (to see when the file gets created), and when I refresh my page the file gets created, which is kinda unnecessary, no? I mean the file itself is not that big (~40KB), but still would be cool if I created the file on button click. Altho I'd have to do AJAX call for that (plus loading the href with the correct file). I'll just put the link in it, like you suggested.

Comment: `$phpexcel->generateXML ( "testfile" );` try this to check file is creating without reload ?

Comment: Doubt this will work, as I don't have this kind of function in my `excel_xml.php` file.

Comment: alternatively you can get the generated last file `$phpexcel->getWorkbook()` and link to the generated file.

Comment: Isn't this kinda the same as `$phpexcel->writeWorkbook('file.xml')`?

Comment: no, it won't be same like get and set. look what comments mention before method, Find `getWorkbook()` here http://php-excel.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.0/Excel_Xml.php